# Vim: "f" breaks my mapping when it can't find a character

Tags: vim

I have a (fairly crude) mapping I want to use for Jade files.

```
nmap <leader>jc ^f)Wc$
```

should turn these examples

```
a.classname(href='url', title='title') Click here
p This is a paragraph
```

into

```
a.classname(href='url', title='title') _
p _
```

where _ is the cursor in insert mode.

However, when `f` can't find `)` it ceases to run the remaining actions in the sequence. Is there a way I can force it to continue with the sequence of commands regardless?

Comment: What does *break* mean in this context?

Comment: What do you want it to do when there isn't a `)`?

Comment: More importantly: why would you want to use a command that assumes the presence of a closing parenthese on some text that doesn't have a closing parenthese?

Comment: @Conner I want it to continue to run.

Comment: @davenichols I do not know what that means. You want it to delete everything from the first space character and go into insert mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

romainl has already tried to convince you that your approach has some flaws.

Anyway, if you want your macro to continue after a command failure, you have to split the sequence of normal mode commands into Ex commands (with `:normal`), as these do not abort:

```
nmap <leader>jc :execute 'normal ^f)'<CR>Wc$
```

Comment: The approach obviously has its flaws, however, the benefit of having one command that produces the same result on `p This is a paragraph`, `p.important This is an important paragraph`, `p.important(attr='val') This is an important paragraph with an attribute`, `p.important(attr='val', attr='val') This is a paragraph with two attributes` outweighs those flaws (in my opinion), as currently there is no `cit` (change inside tag) for Jade.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to need to rethink your problem a bit.

As it is, your mapping is *very* specific, it says:

```
  jump to the first printable character on the line
> jump to the first closing parenthese on the line
  jump to next WORD
  delete from the cursor to the end of the line
  enter insert mode
```

The `jump to the first closing parenthese on the line` part is where the problem is. It means that your whole mapping *depends* on the presence of a closing parenthese in the current line.

Either you keep that mapping in its current state and stop using it where it doesn't make sense (when there's no closing parenthese on the current line) or you redefine your problem so that it can be solved by a generic solution.

A generic solution that *may* involve a bit of scripting. Or not.

***edit***

**This the logic behind your current macro:**

```
1. jump to a specific "anchor" on the line
            |
            V
2. perform an action on whatever comes after that anchor 
   on that line
```

It turns:

```
foo( bar, baz ) lorem ipsum
```

into:

```
foo( bar, baz ) |
```

and rather obviously does nothing on the line below:

```
foo = { "bar" : "baz" }
```

The behavior of your macro is both consistent and predictable. It is taylored to a specific situation and doesn't act up in slightly or completely different situations.

**This is the how you would like it to work:**

```
1.  try to jump to a specific "anchor" on the line
            |
            V
2a. if success: perform an action on whatever comes after that anchor 
    on that line
            |
            V
2b. if failure: perform an action on whatever comes after that anchor 
    on that line
```

It's like… placing a conditional that does nothing in the middle of a function.

It would turn:

```
foo( bar, baz ) lorem ipsum
```

into:

```
foo( bar, baz ) |
```

and:

```
foo = { "bar" : "baz" }
```

into:

```
foo |
```

This would make the behavior of your macro inconsistent: it would work and have vastly varying effects on any line of text. Somehow I think that's not what you want.

For the record, `:^f)Wc$` doesn't "continue". The cursor stays on the first printable character on the line and stops there and this is exactly what `nmap <leader>jc ^f)Wc$` does as well.

In practical terms, you are asking for something like `/)\{-,1}` which would match zero or 1 `)`. But I have serious doubts about the usefulness of such a thing.

Comment: I understand that the mapping is specific. I simply want it to execute the way it does when I run `^f)Wc$` in normal mode.

Comment: @davenichols, why would you do `f)` when there's no `)` on the line?

Comment: I wouldn't. But I would like one mapping that works in either scenario.

Comment: @davenichols, you seriously need to define what "works" and "break" mean, as asked by benjifisher. Your mapping does something after the first `)` on the line, what do you expect it to do when there's no `)`?

Comment: sorry. By "break" I mean cease to continue running the motions/actions listed. I'ved edited my original question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial macro is wrong to begin with because it doesn't seem to map at all with the problem you seem to be trying to solve.

The two examples you finally gave can be done with the same command:

```
^WC
```

Comment: I've editted again for further clarity. But I think the resounding answer is that I can't force vim to behave how I want.